# Chaining Strings in Java

Tags: java, string

let's say that I want to create a new string during a "for" loop,

The new string will be a change of an exsist string that will be change depanding a conditions and positions of the loop.

How can I insert to an exist string new chars?

I went through the whole method summary that relates to strings and didn't get my answer there.

**Edit:** Originaly I posted a java 4 link of methods by mistake. I use the newest version of java.

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for a way of doing this using java 4 ? Or do you linked the wrong javadoc by mistake ?

Comment: By mistake, that's what google gave me, now I see that it is old version. Thanks for mention that.

Comment: @Leo, I thought the version after 1.4.2 was 5.0 ;) There was no "Java 4" or "Java 5" for that matter, there is a "Java 6" ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either use a [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [`String.concat(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29)

**Example:**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Iterator<Integer> iterator =
    Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7).iterator();
if(iterator.hasNext()){
    sb.append(iterator.next());
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        sb.append(',').append(iterator.next());
    }
}
final String joined = sb.toString();
```

---

And about googling javadocs: Google will almost always return ancient 1.4 versions. if you search for keywords like the classname alone. Search for `classname /6`, e.g. `StringBuilder /6` and you will get the current version.

Comment: will the original string will be updated in every rotaion of the loop?

Comment: StringBuffer  is synchronized , performance overhead for non threaded env.

Comment: @Nir not if you use StringBuilder, no. And Strings are immutable anyway, so in any other case new Strings would be created all the time.

Comment: @Suresh that's why I'm using StringBuilder, not StringBuffer

Comment: @Sean saw that and deleted the comment :)

Comment: @sean:now that the string is in String builder mode, what methods can I use for it? If I want to chack what the value of a spesific char?
I think that I miss-concepted it.

Comment: The String is not in Builder mode, StringBuilder is a separate object. When you're done with it, create the String via sb.toString()

Comment: I see, but should i make my operands depanding the StringBuilder or the original string? I want to go through an accepted string doing some things it depanding on some conditions.. so, should i make my string to StringBuilder before that? and if so, can I chack the value of spesific positions? I think that I should simultanions work with both of them?..

Comment: @Nir this is getting too far away from the original question. I guess you will have to ask a separate question in which you provide some code

Answer (score 3):

> How can I insert to an exist string
>   new chars?

You can't. Java strings are designed to be immutable. You'll have to either use a mutable class like `StringBuilder`, or replace the original string with the new, modified version.

Comment: Well... there is reflection... *ahem* ;-)

Comment: @berry even reflection won't let you append data to the string, as the value field is final. But you would be able to change the existing characters

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd Not necessarily true. Interestingly enough, it depends entirely on what version of Java you're using!

http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue096.html

Answer (score 2):

use [`StringBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) for performance reasons:

```
// new StringBuffer
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("bla blub bla");

// insert string
buf.insert(9, " huhu ");

// append strings
buf.append(" at the end");

// Buffer to string
String result = buf.toString();
```

Comment: No, with Java 1.5 or later, use [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). It's faster in all but a few corner cases

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` for even better performance (see above) :)

Comment: i put `StringBuffer` on record because he posted a link to 1.4 java docs

Answer (score 1):

Try `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`. Do you have to code in Java 1.4?

You could also try this (though I highly recommend the `StringBuilder/StringBuffer` approach):

```
String s = "somestring";
s = s.substring(0, 4) + " " + s.substring(4); //result: "some string"
```

You'd need to find the indices for the `substring()` methods somehow (using `indexOf` or `lastIndexOf`).